# Datepicker Binding Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker

```
<DatePicker Date="date" Format="d MMM yyyy" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" x:Name="date"/>
```

By having that line of code in my xaml code. how can i set the date to NOW when i create a new data?

Comment: On the OnAppearing of the page you can set the date.Date= DateTime.Today.

Comment: yes but the problem is when i open an object that is already added and already have a specific date. doing this method will alter the original date from the object

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the `Date` attribute to something like this: `Date="{Binding MyDate}"` and then in your code-behind assign a view model to the `BindingContext` property. For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

and in your page:

```
public class MyPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        viewModel = DateTime.Now;

        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't need to use a view model or MVVM (which I would highly recommend), you can just set it directly from your code-behind. Because you gave the `DatePicker` an `x:Name` attribute, you can refer to it by that name.

```
public class MyPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        date.Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: good idea but the problem is when i open an object that is already added and already have a specific date. doing this method will alter the original date from the object

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve then

Comment: im trying if(date == null){ place the code here..} nothing happens

Comment: What to do if i already have Binding in Date value of DatePicker in Xaml?

Comment: Initialize the `MyDate` variable with the value you want to show initially

Comment: public DateTime dateModelView { get => Model.date == null ? DateTime.Now : Model.date; set { Model.date = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("date"); } }

Answer (score 0):

You can define it in two ways

1. Using the "x:Name" you can define the date in XAML.cs.
2. Using the Binding property for "Date" you can define the date in ViewModel class

In your case in **xaml.cs**

date.Date = DateTime.Now;

Comment: how about if the Object has already a date value in it? it will override the value.

Comment: By default even if you don't set the value for Date to DateTime.Now it will take the default value as DateTime.Now.  If you set a different date it will override the DateTime.now value.

Comment: public DateTime dateModelView
        {
            get => Model.date == null ? DateTime.Now : Model.date;
            set
            {
                Model.date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("date");
            }
        }