# Xamarin.Forms DatePicker.SetValue(BindableProperty, value)

Tags: xamarin.forms

i want to change the value of the Datepicker on code behind

```
 dates.SetValue(BindableProperty?, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datepicker Binding Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239130/datepicker-binding-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

use the `Date` property

```
dates.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: i placed this code after the initializedComponent() and it does not work. when i click new in my app the date is set jan 1,1900.

Comment: btw, the Datepicker is from a contentView